# How restrict video to be open on direct url hit

Tags: content-restriction

i have client website of premium E-learning videos on wordpress. i have uploaded all the videos(MP4) in wp-content/uploads directory. i have problem since it is a premium video i want it such a way that no one can download or see the video with hitting direct file url eg. `http://mywebsite.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/01/video.mp4`

I want to restrict above url from function i also expect file to be work properly in my website though.

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a .htaccess file in order to block the file access from direct url entry.  The below code should work for you.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://(www\.)?yourwebsite\.com/ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !hotlink\.(gif|png|jpg|doc|xls|pdf|html|htm|xlsx|docx|mp4|mov) [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} !^.*wordpress_logged_in.*$ [NC]
RewriteRule .*\.(gif|png|jpg|doc|xls|pdf|html|htm|xlsx|docx|mp4|mov)$ http://yourwebsite.com/ [NC]
```

There is also a previous post on this in the Wordpress Stack exchange on this LINK

[The best way to protect uploaded media in WordPress?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/35226/the-best-way-to-protect-uploaded-media-in-wordpress)

Hope that helps.

Andy

Comment: thanx for reply 
i have implemented above code in .htaccess, its working in case of .mp4 file but not in .jpg and .png
and also can we apply this on .swf file ?

Comment: this code is very good. thank you.
now i want premium users can online view this video only and can't download.
what is htaccess code? best regards
farid parsaei